# Two line entry in xymatrix

Tags: xymatrix

I would like to create a two-lined entry in my xymatrix. In the attached picture, I want to split the direct sum into two lines.

I tried *array* but this didn't work.

Thanks !

[image: pic]

Comment: What you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just brace the `array`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
  {\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}K_0(M_p\oplus M_q)\oplus{}\\ K_0(C([0,1]),M_p\oplus M_q))\end{array}}
  \ar[r] & \\
  K_0(Z_{pq})  \ar[u]^{K_0(\pi_1)\oplus K_0(\pi_2) } \\
  \ar[u]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My sincere welcome. I have deleted, correctly, my answer. Your answer is the best.